# MVVM Light Toolkit 4.5 Set method

Tags: mvvm-light, release

just noticed that 4.2.30 release does not include

```
protected bool Set<T>(
            ref T field,
            T newValue,
            [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            return Set(propertyName, ref field, newValue);
        }
```

Due to compilation constant "CMNATTR" not defined as BUILD argument in release Mode.
Any ideas if it is by mistake or on purpose?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled over this today and would also like to use the [CallerMemberName] with some of the methods MVVMLight provides. Laurent gave an [answer earlier on this issue](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/492941), but it seems that he hasn't has the time yet to fix this. So one option is to download the source, set the symbol and rebuild in release mode. I haven't tried this myself, and I am not sure whether this will have other implications.

Another workaround for now, would be to extend the ViewModelBase and just add the variants of the methods you need, with the [CallerMemberName]. Eg. in your case:

```
public class ViewModelBaseCustom : ViewModelBase
{
    public bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        return this.Set(propertyName, ref field, value);
    }
}
```

and then use this custom version of Laurent's original until MVVMLight has been updated.

Comment: Exactly what I did, compiled w/ CMNATTR. so far it is working great.

Comment: Laurent just commented that a new release is coming next week at Build, including this feature/fix. Source: https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/492941